# Install new Simulator via terminal

Tags: xcode, xcode-simulator

Is there any way to install a new version of Simulator using just cli?
For example - with Xcode 14.0 only iOS 16.0 is build-in to it, what if I want to add an older version of iOS, is it possible that the only way is using Xcode gui..? or there is some cmd that I can use?
(xcversion tool not working with xcode 14 for now :[ )

Comment: Why not just have multiple versions of Xcode installed? Or do you intend to cross mix one Xcode with another higher or lower simulator?

Comment: @bmike I think that the question is why not using one Xcode? It's possible to install older versions of simulators on a newer xcode version, so it's make sense to keep one xcode and multiple versions of simulators.

Comment: My understanding is you need the entire set of frameworks in separate Xcode for the simulator to work.